# Bootstrap validation with php AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, bootstrap-5

I'd like to serialize my form so that it can be sent to a php file via Ajax. I'm using Bootstrap to validate the form beforehand. Unfortunately, the php code returns an empty array.
Bizarrely the debugger seems to show that postData contains the right strings:

> "a_location=abc&a_headline=def"

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    function process_new_post(postData) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"createpost.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:  postData ,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success:function(response)
            {
                alert(response);
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.error("AJAX Request Error:", textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');
        Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
            .forEach(function (form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                    Array.from(form.elements).forEach((input) => {
                       if ( (input.value.trim()==='') && (input.type!=='button') && (input.type!=='submit') ) {
                         input.value = '';
                       }
                    });

                    if ( !form.checkValidity() ) {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                    else {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        process_new_post( $("#formcreatenewpost").serialize() );
                    }
                    form.classList.add('was-validated')
              }, false);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="needs-validation" id="formcreatenewpost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <div class="row g-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a_location" id="a_location" placeholder="Town(s)" required>
                <label for="a_location">Town(s)</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-floating">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a_headline" id="a_headline" placeholder="Headline" required>
                <label for="a_headline">Headline</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 gy-5">                                    
            <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-3" type="submit" id="postcreatenewpost">Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I just checked on my local host.

Don't set contentType and processData as false. Let ajax handle it by itself. Then you will see the values being read on your controller file.

The else block in submit event handler is being called. Logging the postData in script was returning all the values too as you said yourself. The problem is with how you're sending the data.

Comment: Brilliant, it works when I remove those lines. Thank you!